# working with Actionfilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have never worked with actionfilter so i dont really know how to use it, ive done som reseach but i dont completly understand it. But basicly im going to create a new controller, and i want my _Viewstart.cshtml to use this controller. The problem is that i dont know how to use this code to an actionfilter and then call this controller in _viewstart.

The code that i want in my controller is.

```
var TemplateIDSession = Session["TemplateID"];
if (TemplateIDSession != null)
{
int tempID = (int)TemplateIDSession;
var template = servicetemp.GetEntry(tempID);
var servicetemp = ServiceFactory.Instance.CreateTemplateService();

Response.ContentType = "text/css";
return RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("Content/Site.css")));
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @mattytommo when u log in it collects the coid from database and from coid it gets the value from templatetable and then send it to the css, basicly its a webpage that u can log in with different companies, and each company can define some css elements

Comment: @mattytommo This is why i need to call this controller in _Viewstart.cshtml because of: if (Request.IsAuthenticated)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go about this in a different way, by using a HTML Helper for the CSS, like so:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string OrganizationStyleTemplate(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("style");

        var templateIDSession = HttpContext.Current.Session["TemplateID"];

        if (TemplateIDSession != null)
        {
            // retrieve your css from the database and insert it into the tag
            tagBuilder.InnerHtml = dbObject.CSSYouveStored;
        }

        return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
}
```

Then usage would be like so:

```
@Html.OrganizationStyleTemplate()
```

P.S. If you need to analyze if the user is authenticated within that method, use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated
```